# Cite 5 authors in the first citation in your TeX file?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

The APA style manual website says:

> [A]rticles with one or two authors include all names in every in-text citation; articles with three, four, or five authors **include all names in the first in-text citation but are abbreviated to the first author name plus et al. upon subsequent citations**; and articles with six or more authors are abbreviated to the first author name plus et al. for all in-text citations.

Is there a way to

- manually cite all authors in a citation of a paper with 5 authors, using \cite{...}
- have the above-described rule automatically performed by latex, so that I don't have to do it manually?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Use one of the proper APA packages: `apacite` or `biblatex-apa`.  They both handle this automatically.  See [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812) for examples of both methods.

Answer (score 1):

The `apa` style of biblatex will do this automatically (note: you need to use biber instead of bibtex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{companion}

\cite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer not to mess with bibtex, because last time I did this, it created a mess. Is there a way to do this with bibtex? I've tried apacite, but I can't get it to work

Comment: @user56834 Make a save copy of your whole folder, then nothing bad can happen if you create a mess. Other than that I really recommend biblatex, it much better, easer to customize and the syntax is easier to read than what is in bibtex files.